# Spring security: how to configure filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am newbie in Spring, but I try to create extended login form with extra fields and REST authentication. I have custom `AuthenticationProcessingFilter`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
public CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}

private static final String USERNAME_PARAM_KEY   = "username";
private static final String PASSWORD_PARAM_KEY   = "password";
private static final String DEPARTMENT_PARAM_KEY = "department";
private static final String POSITION_PARAM_KEY   = "position";

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String username   = request.getParameter(USERNAME_PARAM_KEY);
    String password   = request.getParameter(PASSWORD_PARAM_KEY);
    Long   department = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter(DEPARTMENT_PARAM_KEY));
    Long   position   = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter(POSITION_PARAM_KEY));
    //custom AuthenticationToken to handle additional fields
    UserSecurityAuthenticationToken userToken = new UserSecurityAuthenticationToken (username, password, department, position);

    return userToken;
   }
}
```

I want to intercept extra login fields here and process them in custom `AuthenticationProvider`:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private AuthentificationService authService;

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException { }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UserSecurityAuthenticationToken token = (UserSecurityAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        return authService.authentificate(token.getName().toString(), token.getCredentials().toString(), token.getDepartment(), token.getPosition());
    }
}
```

I trying to configure filter and provider in `ApplicationSecurity` class using `JavaConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();

        http.addFilter(tokenProcessingFilter());
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean(name="myAuthenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter tokenProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter tokenProcessingFilter = new CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        tokenProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return tokenProcessingFilter;
    }
}
```

But when I try to build the project I receive an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
```

My `Application` class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter webSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new ApplicationSecurity();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `@Bean` method. Also remove `@EnableWebMvc` and just let your `Application` class extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` instead. You can also remove `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` al those are already implied by `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Also you have you own custom filter so configuring the `formLogin` isn't going to do anything that should all be handled by your own filter.

Comment: @M. Deinum, thank you for reply! But how can I implement handlers in my custom filter?

Comment: Just add them... They are just properties of the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` so any filter that extends that can simply have those dependencies set.